# Python 2 vs Python 3 - Difference in map behavior with three arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

The following code behaves differently in Python 2 vs Python 3:

```
all(map(lambda x,y: x, [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]))
```

Python 2 gives `False` whereas Python 3 gives `True`. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) for Python 2 says that it will supply `None` if the shorter list is exhausted but Python 3 [doesn't](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) do that.

I am working on a code that really needs the length to be maintained for some reason. What is the cleanest way to get the old behavior? I know I can use `from past.builtin import map as old_map`, but is there a more elegant solution that would work in both versions?

Comment: can you rewrite the code? perhaps put that functionality in a function without using the differing constructs?

Comment: Why don't you use your own custom function for this purpose?

Comment: @JoachimLusiardi It is a heavily used codey ... so I would like to minimize the changes.

Comment: @mrzrm, Then I could just use `from past.builtin import map` :-)

Comment: How many of the details of your example match what you're really doing? Because `len(list_1) >= len(list_2) and all(list_1)` seems like a much better way to solve the particular problem you show without messing around with backwards compatible versions of `map` or any alternative (like `itertools.zip_longest`).

Comment: @Blckknght I don't think I can change the solution. See this example: `all(map(compare_items, found, expected))`, it seems like the behaviour is really desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, `map` with multiple iterables for the arguments will `zip` the iterables, and then call the function with the tuples from the `zip` as var-args. So, you can get the same behaviour using [`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) and `zip`:

```py
>>> a = [10, 20]
>>> b = [1, 2, 3]
>>> f = lambda x, y: x
>>> list(map(f, a, b))
[10, 20]
>>> from itertools import starmap
>>> list(starmap(f, zip(a, b)))
[10, 20]
```

Then the behaviour you want can be achieved by replacing `zip` with [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```py
>>> from itertools import starmap, zip_longest
>>> list(starmap(f, zip_longest(a, b)))
[10, 20, None]
```

Both functions from `itertools` also exist in Python 2, except the second one is named [`izip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) instead. You can just `import ... as ...` to get around that.